# AS3/Flash Builder - Cannot access a property of a null object reference

Tags: class, flash, actionscript

This is the first time I've used flash builder (I usually just use flash itself for all my AS stuff). I've got a bunch of non static classes and one of them has an issue passing a parameter from a constructor to a private var.

```
private function init():void
{
        var keys:Primes = new Primes();
        var keyArray:Array = [["kdc",keys.getRandomPrime()],["client",keys.getRandomPrime()],["server",keys.getRandomPrime()]];
        trace(keyArray);
        kdc = new KeyDistCentre(keyArray);
        client = new Client(keyArray[1][1]);
        server = new Server(keyArray[2][1]);
}
```

It's the `kdc = new` line which is causing an issue, when I pass keyArray into it it has a problem assigning the value to the private var in the class.

```
package
{
public class KeyDistCentre extends Client
{
    private var keyList:Array = new Array();

    public function KeyDistCentre(keys:Array)
    {
        super(keys[0][1]);

        keyList = keys; **ERROR**
    }

    public function generateTicket():Ticket
    {

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The weird thing is even when I comment out all the problematic lines, the exact same error with line reference occurs...

Comment: According to FB, keyList is null at the point of the error, which I would assume is normal since that's the point of me passing the parameter to it...

Comment: Everything looks good and there is no way you could get a null pointer exception in this line "keyList = keys; **ERROR**". What happens when you pass the value to the super class with "super(keys[0][1]);" ? you are basically just passing one value there, maybe you try to access something in the superclass ? Also sometimes when you get some weird errors that are unlikely to happen, first thing is to do a "Project > Clean" so FB will refresh itself